# Collecting futures in vector, reference lifetime error

Tags: rust, reference, ldap, lifetime, rust-cargo

I am trying to execute an async function using a vector containing arguments, then collect the futures in another vector to join later.

I am getting a compiler error due to passing the ldap argument as a mutable reference `ldap was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the looprustc(E0499)`. I don't get this error when calling the function synchronously with `await()`.

How can fix the lifetime of the ldap argument in run_query()?

Also if anyone has a more idiomatic method of executing a asynchronous function with a vector of arguments please let me know, any help is appreciated thanks!

code:

```rust
use ldap3::{Ldap, LdapConnAsync, Scope, SearchEntry, result::Result};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Query{
    name: String,
    base_dn: String,
    query: String,
    attr: Vec<String>,
}

async fn run_query(ldap: &mut Ldap, query: Query) -> Result<String>{
    // run query
    let (rs, _res) = ldap.search(
        &query.base_dn,
        Scope::Subtree,
        &query.query,
        &query.attr
    ).await?.success()?;

    // output results
    let output = resultentries_to_string(rs).unwrap();
    return Ok(output);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let query = ...Vector of Query struct...
    let (conn, mut ldap) = LdapConnAsync::new("ldap://localhost:389").await?;

    let mut futures:Vec<_> = Vec::new();
    for query in queries{
        futures.push(run_query(&mut ldap, query));
    }
    join_all(futures);
}
```

Full Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `ldap` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/main.rs:174:32
    |
174 |         futures.push(run_query(&mut ldap, query));
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^ `ldap` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

Comment: This can't really be made to work, you're trying to make multiple asynchronous tasks keep a mutable reference to `ldap` but mutable references are exclusive, there can only be one at a time. Having `.await` directly makes them run sequentially and thus doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Well, the way to make it work is to use a wrapper that ensures exclusivity itself, likely with a `Mutex`, but then it looks like it'd have nearly the same behavior as simply `.await`-ing since it would essentially make them run sequentially.

Comment: How expensive is cloning an `Ldap`? That may be another option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is that inisde the for loop you borrow **ldap** multiple times. In the synchronous case it works because you wait for every iteration to end (no multiple mutable borrows of ldap at the same time, which os not the async case).

To overcome this issue, if it is not too expensive, you can clone ldap every time you use a query:

```
for query in queries{
    let mut ldap_clone = ldap.clone()
    futures.push(run_query(&mut ldap_clone, query));
}
```

You also need to change the signature to accept the actual object, not the reference

Comment: I tried this solution but I ran into this error `borrowed value does not live long enough` in reference to the ldap_clone binding. So I changed the `ldap` param in `run_query` from a reference to a mut value and it worked great, thanks!